# Passing string to macro without interpreting it

Tags: slideshow

I'm working on a picture slideshow in beamer. To include each image I wrote a macro, which takes the filename.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\newcommand\pictureslide[1]{%
  \begin{frame}
    \transduration{5}
    \transfade[duration=1]
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{#1}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

%\input{pictureframes.tex}

\pictureslide{/media/ben/External\ Disk/1\ Pictures/_MG_8304.JPG}

\end{document}
```

I wrote some other code that automatically writes a file including all the files of a given folder. The file looks something like the following and gets included in the master .tex file.

```
 \pictureslide{PATH/_MG_1234.JPG}
 \pictureslide{PATH/_MG_1235.JPG}
 ...
```

The error i get is:

```
    ERROR: Missing $ inserted.

    --- TeX said ---
    <inserted text> 
                $
l.25 ...1\ Pictures/_MG_8304.JPG}
```

How can I pass the filename without it being interpreted in math mode? (The filename also contains some spaces, which I protected by using '\ '.)
I suppose the answer is really easy. I tried putting various curly brackets {} around the entire filename to prevent it from being interpreted.

Comment: Is that the only way? I would have to get familiar with it first. Isn't there some way that still uses macros?

Comment: I've never done anything using `\toks`. Can you maybe show me an example?

Comment: why do you say "Due to the underscores LaTeX requires math mode" ? that is only the case if you are typesetting. If you are using those characters as a file path there should be no problem. You have not provided a usable example, so we can not reproduce any error you get, and you didn't say what error you got, so impossible to answer really.

Comment: You should not escape the spaces in the name. Try loading the `grffile` package and enclosing the file name in quotes: `"/media/ben/External Disk/1 Pictures/_MG_8304.JPG"`

Comment: @Ben I just deleted my comments, they don't make much sense. Sorry haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem aren't the underscores, but the spaces: escaping them with the backslash will definitely not work, because `\`  (backslash space) doesn't expand to a space, but is a TeX primitive that basically means “*put a space in the typeset output*” and so it will stop any interpretation of the file name. The `Missing $ inserted` error is a spurious one, due to this incomplete reading of the file name.

Load the `grffile` package and use `"` around the file name (keeping the extension outside):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\newcommand\pictureslide[1]{%
  \begin{frame}
    \transduration{5}
    \transfade[duration=1]
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{#1}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

%\input{pictureframes.tex}

\pictureslide{"/media/ben/External Disk/1 Pictures/_MG_8304".JPG}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this and got the error. Unknown graphics extension .JPG". It works when I simply omit the extension completely. Is there a simple way to get it to work with the extension?

Comment: @Ben Yes: move the closing quotes before the extension. I'll change the code.